# If the impedance of two coils is measured to be identical at 250.0 kHz, is it safe to assume identical impedance across the spectrum?

Tags: impedance, resonance, induction, inductive, coupling

This question pertains to matching two air-gap inductors for use in resonant coupling. Alternative solutions are welcomed and appreciated.

The two coils shall be comprised of identical wire.

The two coils shall be wound with the same means and apparatus, providing identical diameter and spacing of coil windings.

The one variable this means an apparatus cannot ensure is identical length of wire.

I do not own an impedance meter or a variable frequency source of any precision.

I can provide means to generate a stable square wave signal source with four significant digits of precision. This signal source shall have an output impedance of ≤4 Ohms.

One coil will be inserted into an arbitrary filter circuit which shall be driven by the previously described signal source.

The output of this arbitrary filter circuit shall be bridge-rectified in a temperature controlled environment.

The DC potential after rectification shall be measured to 3 significant digits. This voltage shall represent the impedance of the coil.

The second coil shall then be inserted into the previously described filter circuit, and a DC potential produced by identical means.

The length of this second coil will be modified until the DC measurements are identical.

Assuming all of the above, is it reasonable to assume that the frequency response of these two coils will be identical across a the full spectrum?

Comment: @DaveTweed This could probably have served better as an answer. Full-spectrum should literally be assumed to be anything from 0-300 GHz if left undefined. It may be more reasonable to assume 0-6 GHz. Or when speaking of resonant coupling, perhaps assume 0-500 MHz. On a more relevant topic, I would love to hear your opinion on parasitics in an answer. As for cheap LCR meters; I've owned two. Both MCUs overheated under the gob of ferrite. I have no incentive to buy another one, cheap or otherwise, with my current gear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the impedance of two coils is measured to be identical at 250.0kHz, is it safe to assume identical impedance across the spectrum?

Only if the physical construction of the two coils is the same.

If a coil were an ideal inductor, it's reactance would be given by

$$X_L = 2\pi fL$$

and would grow linearly with frequency.

However, a real coil is not ideal, and also has capacitative reactance. This is mostly due to the proximity of one turn to the next. This combination of inductive and capacitative reactances results in the reactance not growing linearly and generally it will actually begin to fall at some point.

If the construction of the two coils is nearly identical, then the curve of reactance with frequency for one coil will probably have nearly the same shape as curve for the other coil. If the two coils have the same reactance at one frequency, they are likely to have similar reactances at a wide range of frequencies.

However, if the two coils have different physical constructions, the fact that their reactances match at one frequency does not entail that their reactances will match over a broad range of frequencies.

A coil manufacturer may or may not give specification for "the" resonant frequency of a coil -- i.e. the point where the inductive and capacitative reactances match. If two coils from different manufacturers list different resonant frequencies for their coils of the same nominal inductance, then it is a sure bet that these coils will not have the same actual inductance reactance at different frequencies, even if they have identical inductance at some particular frequency.

> Assuming all of the above [i.e. that the coils are manufactured similarly, with the air gap being the major variable varying between two coils], is it reasonable to assume that the frequency response of these two coils will be identical across a the full spectrum?

Yes, In the scenario you describe, the two coils *are* manufactured similarly, except that the air gaps of the coils might vary. In that case if the coils match at one frequency, that suggests that the air gaps are in fact quite similar to one another magnetically. Consequently the coils will likely match in reactance over a broad range of frequencies.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is more information than required, and addresses all my questions without getting stuck on the ambiguous nature of my question. Clean, concise, and no jeering at my obviously lacking education on the topic. Some of the most prolific answerers - who's responses are of very high quality - are very snide and condescending. You just showed that tone is unnecessary for a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

> The two coils shall be comprised of identical wire.
>
> The two coils shall be wound with the same means and apparatus,
> providing identical diameter and spacing of coil windings.
>
> **The one variable this means an apparatus cannot ensure is identical length of wire**.

That's a pity, because inductance is critically dependent on the wire length. If you are not controlling this parameter you cannot ensure that the coils will be identical.

> The length of this second coil **will be modified** until the DC
> measurements are identical.

Assuming the wire and coil construction is identical, this should ensure that the length is also identical. However in practice the wire will not be identical. According to [Encyclopedia Magnetica](https://e-magnetica.pl/enamelled_wire/iec_dimensions), for wires below 0.08 mm the resistance may vary up to around ±10%, up to 0.28 mm the variation reduces gradually to ±4%, and for thicker wires it is around ±3%.

Thicker wire has lower resistance per unit length, and so will be longer and have higher inductance for the same resistance.

Another possible problem is stretching. If the wire is thin and has tension to ensure even winding, it could stretch significantly. A 1% increase in length will cause a 2% increase in DC resistance. When you trim the wire back to match the resistance it will be shorter, reducing the inductance.

Both of these problems can be mitigated by counting the number of turns while winding the coil. You may end up with slightly different resistances, but this will probably have less effect on the frequency response than different inductances.

Comment: Thanks you very much. The link you provided is a wealth of knowledge for me on this topic. variance across the length of a conductor never occurred to me. Thankfully there is little stretching involved as I'm using low tension and aluminum magnet wire (aluminum is prevalent in Vietnam). I will measure DC resistance before and after to monitor stretching. I will also take your advice and match the wire length exactly prior to winding the coil (with precisely counted turns). I don't care about resistance as there is no DC component. Self capacitance can be measured precisely after winding.

Answer (score 0):

At DC, the length of the wire determines the resistance.

The number of turns, diameter and length of the coil determines the inductance.

There is capacitance between the wires in the coil.  Capacitance between the layers of wire. There will be a resonant frequency, at the frequency where L and C resonate. The capacitance is dependent on how the layers of wire pile up.  At very high frequency the winding types makes a big difference.  You can wind "random" or inlayers, or scatter wind.

When you make the coil keep the wire tension the same.

Comment: I really don't care about DC characteristics as there is no DC component. Thanks for the advice on self-capacitance. It sounds like you've wound inductive pickups before by your choice of words. This will be a tightly controlled coil of inlayers. I'm aiming for identical capacitance as well as inductance. The winder uses ball bearings, and the tensioning system is an oiled felt pad pressed against the rotating shaft. And there is one 90° turn across a ceramic shaft for friction. Not exactly concentric tensioning. Do you think that tension would be stable enough under those conditions?

Comment: Because I don't know what the spectrum is,  (not DC) and I don't know what the same means it is hard.  My feeling is the coils will be very close to the same thing but only you can say if they are good enough.